# How WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) works

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure I understand completely how `WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)` work to avoid inserting duplicated records in multiple processes environment (containers)

Assume I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UniqueId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I tried to run the below SQL Codes (the first query starts running first) in parallel:

```
declare @id uniqueidentifier;
set @id = '26327A59-8C22-44D9-9339-1FCC8B90181C'

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE uniqueid = @id )
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    INSERT dbo.Test values (@id , 'A')
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WHERE uniqueid = @id 


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And:

```
declare @id uniqueidentifier;
set @id = '26327A59-8C22-44D9-9339-1FCC8B90181C'

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE uniqueid = @id )
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    INSERT dbo.Test values (@id , 'B')
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WHERE uniqueid = @id 


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I got the result, which is correct for me:

```
Id  UniqueId                                Code
29  26327A59-8C22-44D9-9339-1FCC8B90181C    A
```

But I really dont understand how it works, my question why the second INSERT: `INSERT dbo.Test values (@id , 'B')` fails silently?

Comment: It doesn't fail silently, it just gets stuck at the `IF` waiting, then eventually completes but skips the `BEGIN...END` due to the condition. What other possible result could there be?

Comment: @Charlieface: Thanks, looks like it works that way, `WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)` does not allow other transaction to SELECT the same rows?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it does, as documented. Is there anything else you expected to happen?

Comment: @Charlieface what's document you mentioned? if using only (SERIALIZABLE) or (UPDLOCK) it does not work, only works once putting them together

Comment: This is a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#update excellent document. Either way, you don't make clear that your question is really: why does it *not* work when you don't supply one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SERIALIZABLE uses range locking, even locking empty ranges.  UPDLOCK forces U locks instead of shared S locks.

Put them together and you get a U range lock that prevents other sessions from acquiring a U or X lock anywhere in that range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did some research and you're right, the key point here is locking the empty range

Comment: SERIALIZABLE also prevents both sessions from making conflicting changes, but both sessions will get the S range lock, then both will try to get an X lock, resulting in a deadlock.